# Unable to pull value from DateTime object after using ->modify

Tags: php, datetime, object

OK... I'm a bit stumped by this:
I'm trying to use the modify parameter to change a date I'm pulling out of the database before re-saving it:

```
$newExpireDateObj = new DateTime( $oldExpire );
$newExpireDateObj->modify( "+1 day" );
$newExpire = $newExpireDateObj->date;
```

Using January, 5th 2016 as an expiration date I want to extend, this *should* bump the value of `$newExpire` up by a day to 2016-01-06.  But I'm getting nothing.  Here's my Watch panel in PhpStorm showing that it "*Cannot evaluate expression*".

[image: value not being set]

Now here's the messed up part.
If I put a break point anywhere ***above*** the point where I'm setting the value of `$newExpire` and just step through the code -- then it works fine.

[image: value being set]

What... oh what... could I possibly be doing wrong here?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) is what you're looking for.

```
$oldExpire = "2016-01-05 23:59:59";

$newExpireDateObj = new DateTime($oldExpire);
$newExpireDateObj->modify( "+1 day" );
$newExpire = $newExpireDateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $newExpire;
```

Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/JglKY

Comment: Yep.  This is EXACTLY it.  A few minutes after I posted this, I spoke with another developer here at the office and he had suggested the same thing.  Ugh.  What really chaps me is that PhpStorm would show a value with a breakpoint vs. not show one without a breakpoint.  Thanks for the follow-up!